# Why isn't the property attribute being replaced by the right hand side when making assignments?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Given following class (from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property):

```
# using property class
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    # getter
    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    # setter
    def set_temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        if value < -273.15:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273.15 is not possible")
        self._temperature = value

    # creating a property object
    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

when we make assignment `c.temperature = 100` (`c` is an instance of `Celsius`), does anyone know why it calls the setter function, instead of replacing `property` object (which is the original `c.temperature`) with a number `100`?

Comment: Because that's the whole point of the property object... to override the assignment operator, right?

Comment: Because they are descriptors. See the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=descriptors#descriptor-howto-guide).

Comment: What is you very last statement actually doing?

Comment: This seems to be detailed enough: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/property-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the descriptor protocol works. The meaning of `c.temperature = 100` depends on whether `Celsius.temperature` exists. If it does, and `Celsius.temperature.__set__` is defined, then `Celsius.temperature.__set__(c, 100)` is used instead of assigning a value directly to an instance attribute (e.g., `c.__dict__['temperature'] = 100`).

`property` is a type that implements the descriptor protocol. Its `__set__` method calls the setter (`set_temperature`, in your example).

Comment: More precisely, when `c.temperature` is assigned, only `Celsius.temperature` is checked for a `__set__` method. It checks the class before it gets to the instance attribute (assigning a descriptor to an instance's attribute won't invoke it when it's used; it only works when defined on the class). Also, `setattr(c, 'temperature', 100)` will still invoke the descriptor protocol, so it's no different from what you described (you'd need something more ridiculous, like `vars(c)['temperature'] = 100` to bypass it).

Comment: Thanks. I think the changes make the answer more accurate now.